# Hadoop: How does lifecycle of mapper/reducer objects work?

Tags: hadoop

There is a mapper class and a reducer class which are user implemented. In the `map()` function of mapper and `reduce()` function of reducer, should I expect that those functions can be called  my multiple threads on the same `mapper/reducer` object instance? Or are multiple invocations guaranteed to be in same thread? Or is each object only used for one call of `map()/reduce()`, then destroyed, and a new object created for next call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On a high-level, you absolutely cannot *expect* that these run in the same thread.  They actually often run on separate machines, which is what makes MapReduce attractive (ability to run the job on lots of hardware in parallel).

Even if you have a single-machine hadoop cluster or if your map & reduce tasks happen to run on the same node, you still won't share threads, because the task node daemon will generally speaking create a new Java VM for each new task (unless JVM reuse has been configured).

So in general you have to expect that your map and reduce functions are running in isolation from each other, with the any data exchange only occurring through input and output values.

---

The second piece of the puzzle is thread safety between different invocations within a single task.  There is always a single Mapper or Reducer instance in existence for each task, so there is no complexity there to think about.  Within a single instance, execution is controlled by the `run()` method that is part of the Mapper/Reducer API.  Here is the default implementation of run() defined by `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper`:

```
/**
  * Expert users can override this method for more complete control over the
  * execution of the Mapper.
  * @param context
  * @throws IOException
  */
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
  }
  cleanup(context);
}
```

Reducer.run() is similarly structured.  Key takeaways (I'm going to focus on Mapper for the sake of clarity):

- **By default**, map() calls are made **in sequence on a single thread**.
- Your implementation of Mapper is free to introduce multithreading to enable fancy execution orders.
- You are free to introduce shared state on a single instance of Mapper if it helps you process the batch of maps that run within a single task.

### Source code for default implementations:

New API

[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.java)

[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.java)

Old API

[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapRunner.java)

[org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ReduceTask.java) - sequential behavior not overridable.

Comment: It's not that I'm expecting them to run in the same thread. I just want to know if they ever do. Of course I know that they run on many hosts, but they also run many on the same host. So maybe here's another way to ask the question: Hadoop instantiates an instance of the mapper or reducer class. Does it only ever call map() once for each mapper instance, and reduce() once for each reducer instance? My understanding was that the instantiated mapper/reducer object could have its map()/reduce() functions called more than once before being destroyed. No?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question.  I'll add some more details to the answer shortly.

Comment: Your 2nd part was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: "You are free to introduce shared state on a single instance of Mapper if it helps you process the batch of maps that run within a single task." --> Declare a global HashMap(), initialize under setup() and write the key-values inside map(), will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a high level attempt at answering your question but I am going to back up a little bit first.

When your data is being prepared for processing, it is chunked out into one or more [inputSplits](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html). Each split will run in a task with its own instance of a [mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) and that mapper will call the map method for each record (think line) in that split. The mapper instance is not reused.

[Reducers](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html) do more work, but they also are run in one 'task' per reducer.

Comment: So when you say, "Each split will run in a task with its own instance of a mapper and that mapper will call the map method for each record (think line) in that split. The mapper instance is not reused.", is the mapper/reducer class that gets instantiated in each instance used to call map()/reduce() only once? Or the same class instance used multiple times?

To be more clear perhaps, what is the consequence, if any, of storing variables in the mapper/reducer class data rather than in the function body?